# Oracle from java, select all table with blob column affect perfomance?

Tags: java, performance, memory, oracle11g, blob

I´m developing a Java SE app for vet.

I have a table name pets, each pet have a photo that is a blob Column, the question is, when selecting all pets the photo column affect the perfomance of the app?.

In the app I pass the query result to Pet objects i'm thinking when having many rows, the photos charged in memory will affect perfomance.

Comment: You wrote the query and tested it presumably. You tell us, did it have performance issues?

Comment: Do not put blobs in your main table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, it should not affect performance.  Much.  A blob is ultimately just a pointer to an IO stream.  The performance hit comes in when you actually start loading the photos, which will start doing IO operations.  The question is, when do you actually need the image data?

As Thorbjorn pointed out, you probably shouldn't put the blobs in the main table. Either the system has to maintain the table of blob pointers, or your object will have to load image data that it may not need yet. Better to have a separate table with an "imageID" column or somesuch.  Then add a "Pet.loadImage()" method, or maybe an event trigger, that will load the image as needed.